# Writing into text file as tab separated columns in Python

Tags: python

I have two lists

```
A = ["ATTTGTA", "ATTTGTA", "ATTTGTA", "ATTTGTA"]

A_modified = ["ATTGTA", "AAAT", "TTTA"]
```

I want an output tab separated txt file looking like

```
ATTTGTA ATTGTA
ATTTGTA AAAT
ATTTGTA TTTA
```

I tried the following piece of code but it does not write o/p in two columns, just as new rows each time

```
with open ('processed_seq.txt','a') as proc_seqf:
          proc_seqf.write(A)
          proc_seqf.write("\t")
          proc_seqf.write(A_modified)
```

This is the output I get

```
ATTTGTA
    ATTGTA
ATTTGTA
    AAAT
ATTTGTA
    TTTA
```

Comment: I suggest using the `csv` module.

Comment: . write() adds a newline. Just omit it.

Comment: `proc_seqf.write("%s\t%s" % (A, A_modified))` might also work as a replacement for all of your `write()` lines, but using `zip` is probably the best way to get it organized in a meaningful way first, then follow mihai's answer

Comment: I realised this is happening due to the following problem: each of the lists look like A = ["ATTTGTA\n", "ATTTGTA\n",..] and that is why the new line gets added. Can you tell me how to get rid of the \n at the end. thanks

Comment: Just found using str.strip on the strings after reading them from the text file and before creating the string solved all my problems.Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to pair the elements in the two list. You can do that using the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
with open ('processed_seq.txt','a') as proc_seqf:
    for a, am in zip(A, A_modified):
        proc_seqf.write("{}\t{}".format(a, am))
```

I have also used [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) (see [specs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec)) to format the string to get everything in a single line.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this? It provides you with some flexibility in input and output..

```
lines = [
    ['a', 'e', '7', '3'],
    ['b', 'f', '1', '5'],
    ['c', 'g', '2', '10'],
    ['d', 'h', '1', '14'],
    ]

def my_print( lns, spacing = 3 ):
    widths = [max(len(value) for value in column) + spacing
              for column in zip(*lines)]
    proc_seqf = open('processed_seq.txt','a')
    for line in lns:
       pretty = ''.join('%-*s' % item for item in zip(widths, line))
       print(pretty) # debugging print
       proc_seqf.write(pretty + '\n')
    return

my_print( lines )
```

I added the option that the user can decide the size of the spacing..

To match with your example data:

```
A = ["ATTTGTA", "ATTTGTA", "ATTTGTA", "ATTTGTA"]

A_modified = ["ATTGTA", "AAAT", "TTTA"]

lines = [ A, A_modified ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your lists are huge ,i suggest use [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) :

```
import itertools
ac=itertools.cycle(A)
a_mc=itertools.cycle(A_modified)
with open ('processed_seq.txt','a') as proc_seqf:
    for i in A_modified:
      proc_seqf.write("{}\t{}".format(ac.next(), a_mc.next()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from other great answers, as an alternative with `try/except` it will write all remaining elements in the list if their lengths are different (at least in your sample):

```
with open ('processed_seq.txt','w') as proc_seqf:
    for each in range(max(len(A), len(A_modified))):
        try:
            proc_seqf.write("{}\t{}\n".format(A[each], A_modified[each]))
        except IndexError:
            if len(A) > len(A_modified):
                proc_seqf.write("{}\t\n".format(A[each]))
            else:
                proc_seqf.write("\t{}\n".format(A_modified[each]))

cat processed_seq.txt
ATTTGTA ATTGTA
ATTTGTA AAAT
ATTTGTA TTTA
ATTTGTA
```